# Does a static property in a non-staic class get removed by the GC?

Tags: c#

I have a mock database class for unit testing

In each unit test I create a MockDB object and the users added from previously run tests are already there but how long will the static List object last since the class isn't marked as `static`?

```
public class MockDB
{
    public static List<User> users = new List<User>();

    public void Add(User user)
    {
        users.Add(user);
    }

    public void Remove(User user)
    {
        users.Remove(user);
    }

    public User Get(int userId)
    {
        return users.Where(u => u.UserId == userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to write **reliable tests** with such a class and I wonder how you do.

Comment: @SirRufo Which parts are not reliable for you? I'm still trying to figure out the best way to test my code but glad to help share what I'm doing currently.

Comment: A reliable test has a fixed starting condition, which must not depend on when and how often the test is running. You cannot guarantee that with this static mutuable list.

Comment: Couldn't you setup the needed data in the testInit phase? I thought you were asking a question and not correcting my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That cannot ever be collected, since code can access it at any time.

Whether the class is `static` makes no difference.